# Persistent login in Sharepoint 2010 using SessionSecurityToken?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, identity, claims-based-identity

I have a public website which runs on Sharepoint. Now when the users login, we want them to be able to pick "Remember login" so they have a persistent login.

As far as I've understood, Sharepoint supports this. The only thing you have to do, is to run:

`spFederationAuthenticationModule.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(someSessionSecurityToken, true);`

Now, I don't know how to get the SessionSecurityToken that overload requires. Currently we use the one without true.

Our code:

```
MembershipProvider membershipProvider = Membership.Providers["CustomProvider"];

            VerifyCredentialsResult verifyCredentialsDto = null;

            using (WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                var customerService = Kernel.Resolve<ICustomerServiceAgent>();
                verifyCredentialsDto = customerService.VerifyCredentials(userName, passwordOrSsoToken);
                Kernel.ReleaseComponent(customerService);
            }

            if (!verifyCredentialsDto.Succes)
                return false;

            SecurityToken securityToken =
                SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForFormsAuthentication(new Uri(SPContext.Current.Web.Url),
                                                                      "CustomProvider",
                                                                      "CustomRoleProvider",
                                                                      verifyCredentialsDto.CustomerId,
                                                                      passwordOrSsoToken);
            if (securityToken != null)
            {
                SPFederationAuthenticationModule spFederationAuthenticationModule =
                    SPFederationAuthenticationModule.Current;

                spFederationAuthenticationModule.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(securityToken);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
```

Implementing the parameter which is persistent true/false is easy, but how do we change our code to support persistent cookies when logging in?